# Error: Running JavaFX Appl outside Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

everyone!

Here's the thing, I've been developing a **JavaFX application with JDK 7u17** (That's the one Netbeans is compilling it, anyways) and I haven't had any problem testing it and running it through Netbeans itself. I simply click Run and it goes smoothly.

I'm creating the .jar files and the other (html, jnlp) through Clean-Build using Netbeans and the app does open perfectly when I execute the Jar.

The problem is when I try to navigate through the App, the app consists of 4 scenes (Login, Main, Search and Create) with me being able to log-in and head to the main scene but that's about it. The buttons to go to the search scene or create scene don't do anything nor I get an error saying something crashed (note I'm not using the console since I don't even know how to make it appear in runtime). I simply click them and they do nothing.

As I said earlier, the app runs perfectly when it's ran through Netbeans.

Some more info:
Netbeans Version: 8.0
Compilling Version through Netbeans: 1.7u17
Existing Java versions on System: 1.8u25, 1.7u67 and 1.7u17 (I already tried enabling only 1.7u17)

The App used FXML to switch between Scenes, it works great between LogIn and Main scenes.

What could it possibly be that it works great using Netbeans and break outside Netbeans?

EDIT #1:
According to the console (Thanks to @janih) I'm running Java version 1.7u17, same as Netbeans and it looks like it's working properly. The problem persists when I'm trying to run the same jar by simply doubli clicking it. It stops showing me controls (Third party controls).

Comment: Try to start your application using the commandline: `java -jar yourapp.jar`. It will probably print some stack trace or error to the console when you use the application.

Comment: @janih I appreciate your response. I was able to somewhat determine what's the problem. At runtime, it throws exceptions of NoSuchMethodError whenn trying to access objects or classes from an external Jar which is in the library. It's throwing me exceptions like com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager.getPseudoClassMask. I have no idea what to do...

Comment: You are probably running different java versions on NetBeans and on your system(command line). Maybe 1.7 on NetBeans (as you mentioned) and 1.8 on the command line. What does it print when you run `java -version` on the command line? Edit your PATH to include suitable java version or run the Java 1.7/1.8 executable directly.

Comment: At first reading your comment made a lot of sense... But after running java -version, it throws build 1.7.0_17-b02 same as Netbeans. It isn't working either on different computers with different java versions.

Comment: [com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/com/sun/javafx/css/StyleManager.java) seems to be part of OpenJDK and not found on Oracle's JDK. Mixing these implementations can be tricky. Maybe you can uninstall the JDKs and leave only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but it could be this:

I was trying to run a project through the given .jar and had those results but that very Project was a plain JavaFX Project, not exactly JavaFX FXML Project and my Project uses FXML files to change between Scenes. What I did is redo the Project in FXML and worked perfectly.

Special thanks to @janih for the help.